# Can I find a recorded game of nine mens morris?

Tags: nine-mens-morris

I was trying to find dataset from some nine mens morris professional games. But I couldn't find it.

Is there someone who can help me with this?

Comment: Why vote to close? The question is about a computer-based version of board game.

Comment: I've reopened, I don't see a reason to close this.  However, this sounds like you are looking for help with another question. You might want to consider asking your original question .. the one for which you've already determined that you need a dataset to answer.

Answer (score 2):

Board Game Arena has an implementation of the game with 
15,156 of games played.
https://en.boardgamearena.com/#!gamepanel?game=ninemensmorris

I think they might share with you this data, if they do, please let us know
https://en.boardgamearena.com/#!contact